# ConTeXt: Equivalent to \linewidth

Tags: context, width, metapost

I'm thinking about switching from LaTeX to ConTeXt. I'm using LaTeX extensively to create teaching materials with an extended version of `xsim`. There are a lot of things I would need to port, one of them is a macro which produces a number of lines as a writing area for students. In LaTeX I just draw a line with TikZ with `\linewidth`, which returns the width in the current environment (e.g. in an `itemize` environment). I tried to recreate this same behavior with ConTeXt / MetaPost(fun) and it works well with `\textwidth` which returns the full width, independent of the current environment. I could not find any reference to a equivalent of `\linewidth` in the documentations. Is there such a command or a possibility to get the current environments x position?

Here's a minimal example, I would need to replace `\the\textwidth` with something like `\the\linewidth`. There are other issues, like the justification of the text before the break, but this is something I may figure out later.

```
\setuppapersize[A4] 
\setupbodyfont[modern,12pt] 

\starttext

\startuseMPgraphic{line}
draw ((0cm,0cm)--(\the\textwidth,0cm)) ;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\startitemize
  \item here we list the points,\break\useMPgraphic{line}
  \item one after the other.
\stopitemize
\useMPgraphic{line}

\stopchapter
\stoptext
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the site. You can do this:

```
\startuseMPgraphic{line}
numeric hsize ; hsize = \the \ifzeropt\localhsize \hsize \else \localhsize \fi;

draw (0cm,0cm) -- (hsize,0cm);
\stopuseMPgraphic
```

But I think what you try to do is more easily done with `fillinrules`. I give an example below. There I have also removed the setup of paper (A4 is the default)

```
\setupbodyfont[modern, 12pt] 

\starttext

\startitemize
  \item here we list the points,
  \fillinrules[n=2]
  \item one after the other.
\stopitemize
\fillinrules[n=3]

\stoptext
```

[image: example with lines]

You can read more about `fillinrules` [here](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/fillinrules).

Comment: Well, fillinrules makes it simple! Also, thanks a lot for the \hsize and \localhsize reference, this will help with some additional features, e.g. a rectangular, checked region instead a line!